# Find the Characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

The characteristic polynomial of $A \in M_{4}(\Bbb R)$ is: $P(t)= t^4-t$

Find the Characteristic polynomial of:

1. $A^2, A^4$ ($A^4$ was easy but with $A^2$ I'm stuck)
2. Same question with the field $\Bbb F_3$ and $\Bbb F_2$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ has distinct eigenspaces with eigenvalues $0,1,\omega,\bar{\omega}$. So $A^2$ has those same eigenspaces, but with eigenvalues $0^2,1^2,\omega^2,\bar{\omega}^2$. That is, $0,1,\bar{\omega},\omega$. So $A^2$ has characteristic polynomial $x(x-1)(x-\bar{\omega})(x-\omega)$, or $x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, which is just $x^4-x$ again.

In those other fields, the factorization of $P$ to get the four eignevalues may be different. In $\mathbb{F}_2$, the factorization is essentially the same and requires you to use a root in a degree $2$ extension.

In $\mathbb{F}_3$, the polynomial fully factors as $x(x-1)^3$, so there is a repeated root. There may be a dimension three eigenspace, a dimension three shearing space, or a dimension one eigenspace paired with a dimension two shearing space. But whichever way, after squaring there will be a dimension three *something* associated to the $(x-1)^3$ factor. And the argument is basically the same, still leading back to a characteristic polynomial of $x^4-x$.

Comment: Can you explain please how do you know that A^2 has these eigenvalues and eigenspaces?

Comment: What does $A$ do to vectors in each of its eigenspaces? It stretches them by $\lambda$. If you applied $A^2$ to a vector in one of these spaces, then it would be stretched once by $\lambda$ when you apply $A$, _still_ be in that eigenspace, and then stretched again by $\lambda$ with the second application of $A$. In total, such a vector would be scaled by $\lambda^2$.

Comment: In $F_2$ I don't understand the calculation that got to x-2. putting 2 in the polynomial doesn't give 0. ? My factorization came out $t(t-1)^3$

Comment: @user1685224 The $(x-2)$ factor is in the $\mathbb{F}_3$ factorization, not the $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @user685224 Ah I see. I misfactored all of these with an $x^2-x+1$ factor. That's what led to the incorrect $\mathbb{F}_3$ factorization. I will edit.